# iReport and rich text editor printouts

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a question to iReport/JasperReports experts.

I just started to learn JasperReports and iReport.
It looks promising, when you want to print some table reports based on some datasource.

But I have little different requirement.

I have templates prepared in Microsoft Word (typical agreement printout). 
Mostly static text with lots of formating like:

- lists,
- enumerations,
- bolding,
- italic,
- different size fonts,
- margins,
- indentions,
- alignments
- and so on

with very few dynamic fields to fill like name, surname, identity number, ...

I can`t find easy way to implement such rich text editor templates in iReport.

**Is it possible?**

**Is it managable?**

**Is iReport/JasperReports suitable for such rich text editor like printouts?**

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about exporting a report with fields the user can fill in after the report has been run?

Comment: No i am talking about normal report that is filled by some data from data source (but that is not the point). The report I think is rather rich text editor printout than report. And i ask if such rich text editor printouts are siutable to implement in iReport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iReport really just defines the template and formatting of the data printed in the report, so you can use it to set font sizes, styles, margins, indentations, etc. If you're using things like a bulleted list or a numbered list, you may have to improvise some using subreports, but for the most part this type of setup is exactly what iReport does.

Comment: So i guess that doing what i want in iReport is rather tedious task and i should find more appropriate tool.

Comment: There's a degree of tedium in developing any report template if you want it to look good, regardless of the tool you use. iReport is a pretty simple and easy tool to put templates together, and makes the process pretty painless.